# Automatically Import Stock Data - Yahoo Finance & Microsoft Excel

Tags: finance, excel, yahoo

How to import **Growth Estimates: Next 5 years(per annum)** from yahoo finance to microsoft excel?
[image: screenshot from analysis section in yahoo finance regarding importing the value 21.44% from yahoo finance to excel]

Answer (score 2):

If you know about Microsoft Power BI, you can use it and pick which columns of which tables you want to import.
**add tables using examples** button at the bottom as in the attached images.
[image: 1.Import from web]

[image: 2.Import from web URL]

[image: 3.Add Table Using Example]

[image: 4.Import]

Then start to add items from tables then it will complete by itself automatically.
The idea is that you try adding several different items from different tables in the new table in PowerBI then it will automatically collect all other items for these columns into the newly created one.
Later on, when the source on Yahoo got updated your tables will be updated automatically.
You can see more details about this feature on YouTube like these videos:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=add+table+using+examples+power+bi

-Later update-
Power Query in Excel does not include Add Table Using Examples option. check image below.[image: Excel does not include Add Table Using Examples option]

Good luck.
Mohamed

Comment: It's the identical steps as outlined in my answer but a lot better presented!

Comment: My friend, Power Query in Excel does not include the option or feature to add table using examples, and you can check it yourself as it is only available in Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct connection for excel.

[These steps](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/import-yahoo-finance-financial-statements-excel-28682.html) work though.

[image]

Still tedious but Yahoo Finance is what it is. You can use https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/analysis?p=GOOG and combine this with a query that executes for all tickers you would like. The ticker lookup is located [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup).